# Angular Routing broken links

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, localhost, radix, ngroute

I was wondering someone could help me with my Angular project. 
I want to be able to use routing. The problem is that all the links I create refer to localhost/something. Even when I put the base tag in the index.html it won't work.

The basetag looks like this:
`<base href="/routing/"></base>`

The app.js looks like this:
`$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
    }).
    when('/next', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/next.html'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });`

And the home template looks like this: 
`<h1>Home Template</h1>
<a href="/next">Next</a>`

The link when I hover over the anchor tag: 
[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Finaly found out that in the link should be like: <a href="next">Next</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a href="/routing/next">Next</a>`

Is this what you were hoping to achieve?

Comment: Yes, it is but i think there must be a better/cleaner way to do it.